# call a function in python script then check if condition

Tags: python, function, functional-programming

I have this function:

```
def ContentFunc():
        storage = StringIO()
        c = pycurl.Curl()
        c.setopt(c.URL, url)
        c.setopt(c.WRITEFUNCTION, storage.write)
        c.perform()
        c.close()
        content = storage.getvalue()


while True:
        ContentFunc()
        if "word" in content:
             out = open('/tmp/test', 'a+')
```

I want to append `content` from `content = storage.getvalue()`.  But doesn't work.

The ERROR:

```
NameError: name 'content' is not defined
```

Can you help me?

Comment: yes..and append it to test file....

Comment: How about returning something from `ContentFunc`?

Comment: yes...I want to chech if word exists in content then append whole aontent to that file

Comment: @MortezaLSC He's trying to give you a hint. I'll give you one more: What is the scope of the `content` variable inside `ContentFunc`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your function

```
def ContentFunc():
    ...
    content = storage.getvalue()
```

This defines `content` *within the scope of that function*. The function then ends, and that name (and the object assigned to it) is discarded. Instead, `return` from the function:

```
def ContentFunc():
    ...
    return storage.getvalue()
```

and assign the name in the calling function:

```
content = ContentFunc()
```