# How to understand a variable was repeated in python

Tags: python, variables

Imagine I have a function that returns the content of urls inside a loop.
So I have:

```
while True:
    content = ContentFunc()
```

When that line is running in my Python script, how can I understand if the `content` returned is exactly repeated from the `content` returned on the previous iteration of the loop?

## update

How can I understand the word "test" is repeated 10 times or not?

Thank you

Comment: "how can I understand the content exactly is repeated in previous loop?" <-- please elaborate, it is very unclear what you are trying to say here.

Comment: Are you trying to say you're calling `content = ContentFunc()` inside a loop? And you want to know if the value for `content` on the current iteration of the loop is the same as it was on the last iteration?

Comment: I think you must not be a native english speaker, which is fine... but it is very hard to understand what you are asking here..

Comment: The OP asked this question recently, which possibly gives some more context: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23833697/call-a-function-in-python-script-then-check-if-condition

Comment: When I call ContentFunc it returns me content of a url page from bing search. How can I understand this url page cntent had repeated before?

Comment: No @ dano This is not what I asked before :)

Comment: @MortezaLSC Do you want to know if it's repeated from the last iteration, or if it's __ever__ been repeated?

Comment: Yes I mean  last iteration exactly...

Comment: @MortezaLSC Yes, I know it's not a dupe of that question. But reading that helped me understand what you were trying to ask here, so I included for everyone else, too.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can check for an exact repeat like this, assuming `content` is just a `str` and not a custom object:

```
prev_content = ""
while True:
  content = ContentFunc()
  if content == prev_content:
      print("Same as last time")
  prev_content = content
```

You just store the result of the previous iteration in a variable (`prev_content`), and compare it to the result you get for the current iteration.

Comment: Thank you...I would be thankful if you also help me in this: How can I understand in each content one word is repeated 10 times or not? thank you

Comment: @MortezaLSC You mean if a word is repeated ten times in `content`? If yes: `if content.count("word") == 10:`